# maven pom cannot import expectant version

Tags: java, selenium

I want to limit the selenium-java version of the project to 3.8.1 .Of course selenium- Java also has many dependencies in its pom with same version.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <classifier></classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <classifier></classifier>
</dependency>
...
...
```

I suspect this will help me set up dependencies versions such as `selenium-chrome-driver` to 3.8.1 .
However, the actual version introduced in my project is 3.141.59(the latest version), so I need to set up their version one by one.It seems silly, So I was wondering if there's any easy way to solve this problem.I have excluded selenium-java introduced in other projects through `exclusion` tag.

[dependency tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCRM2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Define version as a property. It can look as follows:

```
<properties>
    <selenium.version>3.8.1</selenium.version>
</properties>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
  <version>${selenium.version}</version>
  <classifier></classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
  <version>${selenium.version}</version>
  <classifier></classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I will try this method,But why can't they inherit the version defined in `selenium-java`?

Comment: There is no inheritance. But you can replace hardcoded version also for selenium-java, and if have some Selenium libraries - also for those. So that you have for all Selenium libraries a single point where the version is defined.